# Data Validation + VLOOKUP for Month in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

So I'm currently setting up a sheet that records weekly numbers. I'd love to have something that summarizes the totals (money in, loss, etc) by month. So if the week =  4/4/0 this is April (4) and is calculated just by a drop-down of months. Is such a thing possible in Sheets? I don't need the formula just the clue, really.

[image]

Update:

I found something similar:

`=SUMIFS($N$7:$N$11,$M$7:$M$11,">="&S8,$M$7:$M$11,"<="&EOMONTH(S8,0))`

N7:N11 is amount
M7:M11 is date
S8 is the date I'm querying for

The issue I have with that (^^) formula is that it wants me to present the date as D-MONTH-YYYY
but I'd love the date to just be the MONTH

[image]

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column to show just the month by setting its format:

[image: custom-format-sheets]

and creating a "Custom date & time"

---

Alternatively, you can use text to represent the months and convert them to number representation using `MONTH(S8&1)`

Then, you can do some funky way of converting the "month" to "date" using `DATE(YEAR, MONTH(S8&1), 1)`, where "year" is the year you're querying for.

To sum it up, the formula from your question might look something like this:

`=SUMIFS($N$7:$N$11, $M$7:$M$11, ">="&DATE(2022, MONTH(S8&1), 1), $M$7:$M$11, "<="&EOMONTH(2022, MONTH(S8&1), 1),0))`